# Ubuntu 18.04.3 Installation Issue

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

So, basically when I try to install Ubuntu 18.04.3 alongside Windows 10, I reach the step where it asks me to choose between Normal Installation and Minimal Installation. When I click on the Normal Installtion and hit continue, it just keeps loading and doesn't go to the next step. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you verify your download of the ISO? or more importantly your write to install media?  (using the '*check disc for defects*' option).  That would be my first step in your position, as if either download or write to media wasn't perfect, you'll be wasting hours-days chasing problems that 60secs of validation can quickly detect..

Comment: I had the same problem but my hard disk was the cause https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156764/can-bad-sectors-cause-ubuntu-installer-to-freeze